# adb shell settings put with default value... What is TAG parameter?

Tags: adb, settings

I want to set value and default value of a setting with `adb shell settings`.
But to set default I also need to specify the `TAG` parameter. What is this ?

`put [--user <USER_ID> | current] NAMESPACE KEY VALUE [TAG] [default]`

Can I specify anything or are there some "safe" values for `TAG` parameter? Where it goes?

Comment: Tag is just a comment. For system settings I've never seen it set to any value other than "null".